# "sudo -l" says I can sudoedit a file, but won't let me

Tags: ubuntu, sudo, sudoedit

I am logged into my system, and when I type `sudo -l` it shows:

```
$ sudo -l
Matching Defaults entries for user1 on WINNING:
    env_reset, mail_badpass,
    secure_path=/usr/local/sbin\:/usr/local/bin\:/usr/sbin\:/usr/bin\:/sbin\:/bin

User user1 may run the following commands on WINNING:
    (root) NOPASSWD: sudoedit
        /var/www/html/test/*/*/layout.html
```

When I attempt to then edit a layout HTML file in that path, I get the following:

```
$ sudoedit cupoftee/templates/layout.html
sudoedit: no tty present and no askpass program specified
```

Why won't it let me edit?  Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Your headline says 'cant', but I guess you wanted to write 'can'. Username is werkzeug or user1?

Comment: Have you tried giving the complete path to the file to edit? I'm not sure the sudo ecosystem ever does more than simple pattern matching. (No man page handy.)

Answer (score 1):

The `sudo -l` command says

```
User user1 may run the following commands on WINNING:
    (root) NOPASSWD: sudoedit
        /var/www/html/test/*/*/layout.html
```

This means that you are allowed to use `sudoedit` on any path that looks like

```
/var/www/html/test/*/*/layout.html
```

Your command,

```
sudoedit cupoftee/templates/layout.html
```

invokes `sudoedit` on a path that does not match that pattern, so it will not allow you to do it.

Instead, do

```
sudoedit /var/www/html/test/cupoftee/templates/layout.html
```

Note: I don't know if that's the correct absolute path to the file you're trying to edit.

Comment: my desired end goal is a root shell, so i was hoping to accomplish something akin to:    `sudoedit /var/www/html/test/cupoftee/templates/layout.html` and then in vim, do: `:shell` to pop a shell with the permissions of the own, which would root... i hope.

Comment: @Fallenreaper It will _not_ be a root shell.

Comment: @Fallenreaper `sudoedit` invokes the editor as your unprivileged user on a temporary file. When exiting the editor, the file is moved into place and it's permission and ownership are changed.

Comment: Well that is good to know. Good thing that is in place, or there would be far too many loose ends on servers.  Bad news for me trying to find a way to elevate myself.

Comment: @Fallenreaper Talk to your sysadmin/manager about it. This is not a technical "problem" but a social/bureaucratic/legal one. Trying to circumvent security measures may also get you fired/expelled/prosecuted.

Comment: oh for sure.  They wanted me to get root.  I was looking at different vectors on the box and after all my enumeration, it looked at the `sudo -l` for the user i got a low level shell on and was thinking this just might've given me the resolution I needed.

Comment: If  user1 is authorised running sudoedit without full path, it is a child´s play to get `root`....Tell that to your sysadmin.